# Laravel undefined variable in view file

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

I am getting an error in laravel 5.3.9 on the dashboard view with an undefined variable posts. I am trying to list all the posts from the user that he has in the database. Here is my code so far:

UserController.php

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class UserController extends Controller 
{
    public function postSignUp(Request $request) 
    {   
        // Validate the entry of the sign up form
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'      => 'email | required | unique:users',
            'first_name' => 'required | max:120',
            'password'   => 'required | min:6'
        ]);

        $email = $request['email'];
        $first_name = $request['first_name'];
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->first_name = $first_name;
        $user->password = $password;

        $user->save();

        Auth::attempt($user);

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');

    }

    public function postSignIn(Request $request) 
    {
        // Validate the sign in form
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'      => 'email | required',
            'password'   => 'required | min:6'
        ]);

        if( Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']]) ) {
            return view('dashboard');
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}

?>
```

PostController.php

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller 
{
    public function getDashboard()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('dashboard', [ 'posts' => $posts ]);
    }

    public function postCreatePost(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the post text field
        $this->validate($request, [
            'body' => 'required | max:1000'
        ]);

        $post = new Post();
        $post->body = $request['body'];
        $message  = "There was an error";

        if( $request->user()->posts()->save($post) ) {
            $message = "Post succesfully created";
        }
        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with([ 'message' => $message ])->compact($posts);
    }

    public function getDeletePost($post_id) 
    {
        $post = Post::where('id', $post_id)->first();
        $post->delete();

        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message' => 'Post succesfully deleted']);
    }
}
```

dashboard.blade.php

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
        <article class="post">
            <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
            <div class="info">
                Posted by {{ $post->user->first_name }} on {{ $post->user->created_at }}
            </div>
            <div class="interaction">
                <a href="#">Like</a> |
                <a href="#">Dislike</a> |
                <a href="#">Edit</a> |
                <a href="{{ route('post.delete', [ 'post_id' => $post->id ]) }}">Delete</a> 
            </div>
        </article>
        @endforeach
```

web.app routes

```
    <?php

use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are handled
| by your application. Just tell Laravel the URIs it should respond
| to using a Closure or controller method. Build something great!
|
*/

Route::group( ['middleware' => ['web']], function() 
{
    Route::get( '/', function () {
      return view('welcome');
    })->name('home');

    // Route for signed up users
    Route::post( '/signup', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
        'as'   => 'signup'
    ]);

    // Redirect to signin
    Route::post( '/signin', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@postSignIn',
        'as'   => 'signin'
    ]);

    //Redirect to the dashboard
    Route::get('/dashboard', [
        'uses'       => 'PostController@getDashboard',
        'as'         => 'dashboard',
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);

    // Create a new post and route
    Route::post('/createpost', [
        'uses' => 'PostController@postCreatePost',
        'as'   => 'post.create'
    ]);

    // Create a new post and route
    Route::get('/delete-post/{post_id}', [
        'uses'       => 'PostController@getDeletePost',
        'as'         => 'post.delete',
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);

});
```

And the error that i get

```
    ErrorException in 3bda00b66abf627abd64dcb541751a9b753d4384.php line 33:
Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\wamp\www\laravel\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)
    in 3bda00b66abf627abd64dcb541751a9b753d4384.php line 33
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\wamp\www\laravel\storage\framework\views/3bda00b66abf627abd64dcb541751a9b753d4384.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\wamp\www\laravel\resources\views/dashboard.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in View.php line 150
at View->getContents() in View.php line 121
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 86
at View->render() in Response.php line 45
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 201
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 1042
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in Router.php line 642
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 644
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

I am not sure how to pass $posts variables to the view files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$posts` is null, you might face that error. You can try encapsulating foreach with

```
@if (isset($posts))
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
    ...
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: This is working and the error from the page is removed however not it's not displaying any of the posts that the user has inside the database.

Comment: Then probably your Post::all() is returning null. You can check your Post model and database records.

Comment: I found what the problem is UserController.php
return view('dashboard');
should be   
return redirect()->route('dashboard'); otherwise it goes to /signin route.

Comment: Cheers you found it :)

Answer (score 0):

You first want to check at the controller if $post is returning any data. So right after this line;

> $posts = Post::all();

Do a

> dd($posts);

If this returns any records, then you can then examine your view. As @berkayk's answer mentioned. You should be doing some checks at your view to ensure your view doesn't throw an error OR return a different view altogether by checking the record count at the controller.